# Reinterpret cast in c

Tags: c++, c, casting, codec

I have some operation like this C++ code that I want to convert in C89:

`return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(stream.buffer) - buffer;`

How can I replace the reinterpret cast in C?

Comment: In C there has always only been one type of cast.

Comment: `How can I replace the reinterpret cast in C` you cannot replace something that does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing very exciting, you've seen this before:

```
(uint8_t *)(stream.buffer)
```

That's the only way to cast something in C.

Comment: so the reinterpret cast do really nothing more that a "classic" cast?

Comment: Pretty much. C++ has other kinds of casts that C does not have. However it's not exactly a one-to-one match. `reinterpret_cast` does not do what a C-style cast does for casting to a subclass.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a C style cast:

```
(uint8_t*)stream.buffer
```